# Pagination Review

Tags: php, pagination

I went through lots of tutorial, and almost all of them were quite long, so I came up with my own code:

```
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  $pg_count = $page-1;

  if ($page == 1) {

    $start = 0;

  } else {

    $start = $pg_count*15;

  }

  $limit = $page*15;

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';

  foreach($db->query($query) as $row) {

    //outputs

  }

  $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table'); 
  $row_count = $stmt->rowCount(); 

  $count = ceil($row_count/15);

  for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {

  echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

  }
```

Here i'm displaying 15 results per page.

This small piece of code seems to do the job (new to pdo, sorry if the method of including parameter is wrong).

So basically my question is, is their a much better way to do this?

EDIT:

I couldn't figure out a good approach so I came up with this horrible code:

```
if ($page != 1) {


  if ($page > 5) {

    $sdot = '....';

  } else {

    $sdot = '';

  }

  echo '<a href="?page=1" class="page" >First</a>'.$sdot ;

}


  if ($page < 5) {

    for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {

      echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

    }

  } elseif (($page > 5) && ($page < ($count-5))) {

    for ($i=($page-2); $i<=($page+2); $i++) {

      echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

    }

  } elseif (($page > ($count-7)) && ($page < ($count-2))) {

    for ($i=($page-2); $i<=($page+2); $i++) {

      echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

    }

  } else {

    for ($i=($page-2); $i<=$count; $i++) {

      echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

    }

  }


if ($page != $count) {

  if ($page < ($count-2)) {

    $edot = '....';

  } else {

    $edot = '';

  }

  echo $edot.'<a href="?page='.$count.'" class="page">Last</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pagination code that I used in one of my old applications. You should change the mysql_ functions to pdo/mysqli here. This is based on a simple table with id, name fields. Change the queries according to your logic.

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// get total no. of rows from the table
$page_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM table";
$RSp = MYSQL_QUERY($page_query) or die(mysql_error());
$rowp = mysql_fetch_array($RSp, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$num_rows = $rowp['C'];
$rows_per_page = 100;      // you can change this to what you want
$first = 1;
$last = ceil ($num_rows/$rows_per_page);

if (($page == '') || ($page < $first) || ($page > $last)){
    $page = 1;
}

$lower_limit = (($page-1)*$rows_per_page);
$count = 0;

// main query to generate page content based on 
// pagination logic
$query = "Select * from table order by name ";
$query.= "LIMIT ".$lower_limit.", ".$rows_per_page;

// generate page content here
// pagination code at the bottom of the page goes here

<!--This is the main pagination HTML Code-->
<ul id="pagination-clean">
<?php
 if ($page == 1){
?>
     <li class="previous-off">Previous</li>
<?php
}
else {
?>
    <li class="previous"><a href="?page=<?php echo ($page-1); ?>">Previous</a></li>
<?php
} // end else
for ($i = 1; $i<=$last;$i++){
    // This is the query statement for displaying the name of 
    // first and last entry of the page 
    // on paginated links
    $lower = (($i-1) * $rows_per_page);
    $upper = (($i*$rows_per_page) - 1);

    $query_low = "SELECT Name, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 2) AS `Name_S` FROM ";
    $query_low.=  "table ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT ".$lower.", 1";
    $RSl = MYSQL_QUERY($query_low) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_low = mysql_fetch_array($RSl, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $lname = $row_low['Name'];
    $lname_s = $row_low['Name_S'];

    $query_up = "SELECT Name, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 2) AS `Name_S` FROM ";
    $query_up.= "table ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT ".$upper.", 1";
    $RSu = MYSQL_QUERY($query_up) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_up = mysql_fetch_array($RSu, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if (!$row_up){
        $query_up = "SELECT Name, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 2) AS `Name_S` FROM ";
        $query_up.= "table ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT ".($num_rows-1).", 1";
        $RSu = MYSQL_QUERY($query_up) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_up = mysql_fetch_array($RSu, MYSQL_ASSOC);        
    }
    $uname = $row_up['Name'];
    $uname_s = $row_up['Name_S'];

    if ($i == $page){
?>
        <li class="previous-off"><?php echo $i ." (".$lname_s." - ".$uname_s.")"; ?></li>
<?php
  }
   else {
 ?>
       <li><a href="?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo $i ." (".$lname_s." - ".$uname_s.")"; ?></a></li>
<?php
    }
  } // end for loop

  if ($page == $last){
?>
        <li class="next-off">Next</li>
<?php
}
else {
?>    
    <li class="next"><a href="?page=<?PHP echo ($page+1)?>">Next</a></li>
<?php
 }
?>
</ul>
  <!-- end pagination code here -->
```

This is the CSS:

```
#pagination-clean li          { border:0; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:11px;       list-style:none; /* savers */ float:left; }
/* savers #pagination-clean li,*/
#pagination-clean a           { border-right:solid 1px #DEDEDE; margin-right:2px; }
#pagination-clean .previous-off,
#pagination-clean .next-off   { color:#888888; display:block; float:left; font-weight:bold; padding:3px 4px; }  
#pagination-clean .next a,
#pagination-clean previous a  { border:none; font-weight:bold; }  
#pagination-clean .active     { color:#000000; font-weight:bold; display:block; float:left; padding:4px 6px; /* savers */ border-right:solid 1px #DEDEDE; }
#pagination-clean a:link,
#pagination-clean a:visited   { color:#0e509e; display:block; float:left; padding:3px 6px; text-decoration:underline; }
#pagination-clean a:hover     { text-decoration:none;
```

This is a screenshot of what the page looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3px7n.jpg

(In addition to the page no., it also displays the first 2 characters of the name field)

See if this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes it is good, but can you point out improvements in my code, as it also works, and I can add css later on and I have `isset` check on `$_GET['page']`..

Comment: since your code works fine, the only improvement that I can think of would be making rows per page parameter dynamic so that you can easily switch from 15 rows per page to any no. of rows you want. Other improvement could be this part: if (($page == '') || ($page < $first) || ($page > $last)){
    $page = 1;
}

Comment: what you might also want to do is test your case for different page values and see if it handles all the cases correctly. Other than that it looks good.

Comment: Yes, i tested it for 50 values, and yes thanks for next and last thing, and how can I do something like `First 1 2...8 9(current page) 10...81 82 last`

Comment: can you clarify that a bit more ?

Comment: never mind... I see what you are saying.

Comment: Like if i have 100 pages, and I'm on 9th page, it should display something like `..7 8 9 10 11..` where 9 is the current page..

Comment: ok... do you wanna give it a shot on your own using your or my code as a starting point? I can give you a hint: the change needs to be made in the for loop and you might have to declare some additional variable and add some more condition checking same as what I did in my code. If you can get it then you might want to reply here tomorrow and I'll see if I can work with you on this.

Comment: Yea sure, I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: Ok I tried, couldn't figure out, so I came up with a lot of `if` statements(posted the code in the edit of the question). How can you do with adding just one more loop? :o

Comment: ok... I'll take a look at it as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: you wanna give this a shot: http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/ ?

Comment: Yes, that looks awesome :) still I would like to know how would you compress those `if` statements to single loop, might help in the future..

Comment: were you able to create what you wanted combining the code from that link and your or my answer? Understand that for an application like this, there would always be a certain minimum no. of if loops that would be needed.

Comment: Ok I get your point, thanks for your help :)

Comment: yeah try that and if that does not work then you can create another question here and someone can review it too.